# Anyone Use Brewjacket

Tags: fermentation, temperature

I was thinking about getting a Brewjacket to control my fermentation temps. Anyone use one? I'm wondering if the $400 pricetag is worth it. Seems like it is.

Answer (score 1):

I never used one, but I did a little research for you.

It claims to be able to ferment up to 35º above or below your room's ambient temperature, which is great since a mini fridge would cool but not heat your wort.

Biggest negative point (besides the price tag) is that it doesn't seem to work with a glass carboy.  Assuming you want to use it with a carboy, it would have to be a plastic one.

Here is one comment from amazon:

> After receiving the brew jacket pro I can only say it's a disappointment it does not work with glass carboy only plastic and that is limited. The tiny port cloggs with. Very active fermenting beers. The jacket is cumbersome to use and required. The temp sensor is external wine cider require an external sleeve not included need special sanatizing solution. After cleaning up the mess. Temp appears to be holding but it's usefulness is yet to be determined. Be aware of its limited usefulness before you buy or gift. There is better brewing equipment that cost less and would be more useful.

The idea is great, it is not as cumbersome as a fridge, but for the price you decide if it's worth buying...

Answer (score 0):

For the price, couldn't you just get a decent mini fridge and a temperature controller? Better yet go over that 400 by 10-20 percent and get an entry level kegerator. There are plenty in the 350 to 450 range, some with internal temperature controllers.

An added bonus with the fridge is you can have the option to keg in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using **Keg Cooler Mini 9,4 l - Cool Brewing** 
It's cheaper than what you are looking, I put a bottle of ice to cool down changing it per day if needed.